# Error: str' object is not callable when attempting to loop over list using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use pandas and BeautifulSoup to create a dataset on crowdsourcing campaigns. URLs for all the pages I want to scrape are stored in a text file with three tab-separated columns: url, position (the campaign's position on the homepage), and category. My goal is to loop over each url and save the url, catgory, position, and other information as variables in a new dataset. I'm able to get below code to work when I run it on a single url, but when I try to loop over the urls, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-2a05d3cebea0> in <module>
     21 position = df['position'].tolist()
     22 
---> 23 for url, category, position in zip(url, category, position):
     24 
     25     page = requests.get(url)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I assume the problem is related to my reading in the urls from the .txt file as a list, but I'm unsure how I should change the code so that 'url' is callable. This is the full code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
import requests
import json

df = pd.read_csv('url_list_01.txt', sep = " ", delimiter= None)

# Dropping row number column because I don't actually need it, it was just there

df = df.drop(columns=['row'])

# Converting columns into lisst so I can loop over them.

for newcol in ['title','zip','amount_raised','goal','donations','campaign_start','shares','hearts','text']:
        df[newcol]=0

url = df['url'].tolist()
category = df['category'].tolist()
position = df['position'].tolist()

for url, category, position in zip(url, category, position):

    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    page = page.content

    df['title'] = soup.find_all('h1', class_='a-campaign-title')[0].get_text()

    zip = str(page,'utf-8').split('postal_code":"')[1]
    df['zip'] = zip.split('"},"is_partner')[0]

    amount_raised = soup.find_all('h2', class_='m-progress-meter-heading')[0].get_text()
    df['amount_raised'] = amount_raised.split(" ")[0]

    goal = soup.find_all('h2', class_='m-progress-meter-heading')[0].get_text()
    df['goal'] = goal.split(" ")[0]

    donations = str(page,'utf-8').split('donation_count":')[1]
    df['donations'] = donations.split(',"comments_enabled"')[0]

    campaign_start = str(page,'utf-8').split('launch_date":')[1]
    df['campaign_start'] = campaign_start.split(',"campaign_hearts"')[0]

    shares = str(page,'utf-8').split('social_share_total":')[1]
    df['shares'] = shares.split(',"social_share_last_update"')[0]

    hearts = str(page,'utf-8').split('campaign_hearts":')[1]
    df['hearts'] = hearts.split(',"social_share_total"')[0]

    df['text'] = soup.find_all('div', class_='o-campaign-story')[0].get_text()

    df['url'] = url
    df['category'] = category
    df['position'] = position

    df.to_csv('data_01.csv', mode = 'a', header = 'column_names', sep=',', line_terminator='\n')
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is there anywhere in your code that you haven't shown, where you've accidentally assigned something to `zip`? Perhaps `zip='zip'`? What do you get if you do `type(zip)`?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say your error stems from using the builtin `zip` name as a variable, which should never be done. Also, it can't be good to re-use the same name for the iterator as well as the inputs of `zip()`. Don't write `for url, category, position in zip(url, category, position):`, write `for u, c, p in zip(url, category, position):` or something.

Comment: `zip = str(page,'utf-8').split('postal_code":"')[1]` -- there's your problem. And as mentioned above, you've overwritten multiple variables in your program.

Comment: Consider `url = df['url'].tolist()`, I'd call that variable `urls` or `url_list` (better) so that a future enumeration such as `for url in url_list:` naturally documents what you are doing.